# Google Cloud Function persists data between http function calls

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I've discovered some weird behavior which I now know how to ship around but which I don't understand why it is happening:

I have a HTTP cloud function that recalculates some statistics for a user. If I call the function for user 1 it works fine. If I then call it for user 2 it overwrites user 2's data with the data from user 1!

```js
const emptyObj = {
    key: "value",
    count: 0
}

async function getStats(userId: string): Promise<any> {
    // This will apply the user 1 stats to user 2
    const stats = emptyObj;
    // This will NOT apply the user 1 stats to user 2
    // const stats = { ...emptyObj };

    // Do some stuff, modify stats
    // or don't do anything if new user (user 2!) 

    return stats;
}

export const recalcAllStatsForUser = functions
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    const newStats = await getStats(request.query.userId);

    // Save new stats to DB
    const userRef = db.doc("users/" + userId);
    return db
    .runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
      transaction.update(userRef, {
        stats: newStats,
      });
    })...
}
```

Why does the cloud function somehow "persist" the emptyObj data from user 1 and reuses it later one when again calling "const stats = emptyObj;" for user 2?
And why is it working if I'm doing the shallow copy of emptyObj with "{...emptyObj)"? I never change the reference to emptyObj.

Answer (score 0):

You have some explanation in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#function_scope_versus_global_scope).

To summarize it, imagine that when you trigger a Cloud Functions, you start your webserver.

1. If you have several successive request, the webserver is still up and running and serve your requests. Therefore, variable in memory are already here, in memory.
2. If you stop your webserver, and start it again, or run it on another computer, your app start from 0 with no value in memory.

The #1 is what happen in Cloud Functions when you have different request on the same instance (note that the requests must be subsequent, concurrency is not allowed on Cloud Functions. if 2 concurrent requests, 2 Cloud Functions instances are created and work concurrently. Never 2 requests in the same time on the same instance.)

The #2 happens when Cloud Functions scale out (run on another computer) or when you no longer use Cloud Functions (the instance is offloaded, the webserver stopped. If you send a new request, a new instance is started and thus a new webserver.)

Comment: To improve this answer, you should also cover mutating objects by reference which is what this code is also doing.